# Does form_valid() in CBV not call is_valid() method?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-class-based-views, django-validation

When I used function views, It was able to handle cleaned_data with overriding form.clean() method. I thought when I call form.is_valid method, form.clean() is called too.

> Form validation happens when the data is cleaned. If you want to customize this process, there are various places to make changes, each one serving a different purpose. Three types of cleaning methods are run during form processing. These are normally executed when you call the is_valid() method on a form.

Now I'm trying to do same things with class-based-view, but it does not work as I thought.

Here's my forms.py:

```
class PublishForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Article
        exclude = [
           'author',    
         ]

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        self.user = user
        return super(PublishForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def is_valid(self):
        print('IS_VALID METHOD CALLED')
        return super(PublishForm, self).is_valid()

    def clean(self):
        print('CLEAN METHOD CALLED')
        cleaned = super(PublishForm, self).clean()
        cleaned['author'] = self.user
        return cleaned
```

views.py:

```
class PublishView(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = forms.PublishForm
    success_url = '/'
    template_name = 'ex00/publish.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        print(form.cleaned_data)
        return super(PublishView, self).form_valid(form)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        print(form.errors)
        return super(PublishView, self).form_invalid(form)
```

and urls.py:

```
app_name = 'ex00'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('articles/', views.ShowArticlesView.as_view(), name='show-articles'),
    path('detail/<slug:slug>/', views.ArticleDetailView.as_view(), name='article-detail'),
    path('favourites/', views.FavouriteArticlesView.as_view(), name='favourite-articles'),
    path('login/', views.LogInView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('logout/', views.LogOutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    path('like/', views.LikeView.as_view(), name='like'),
    path('register/', views.RegisterView.as_view(), name='register'),
    path('publish/', views.PublishView.as_view(), name='publish'),
]
```

It seems form_valid() does not call neither form.is_valid() or form.clean(). But It was able to get form.cleaned_data().

How does form_valid() work?
What should I do to manipulate cleaned_data like I did it with form.is_valid()?

Addition: [image]

I can see the message `POST CALLED`. But cannot see when added `print` at `ProcessFormView` that inherited by `PublishView`.

console:
[image]

my template:

```
{% extends 'share/base.html' %}
{% load django_bootstrap5 %}
{% block title %}Publishing Article{% endblock %}
{% block style %}
<style>
</style>
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <form method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
        {{form}}
        <input type="submit" value="Post">
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: No, this is done in the `post` method.

Comment: Are these all the url patterns (is this the "root" `urls.py`, or are there other such views)?

Comment: Can you also share the *template* where you render the form (and the `<form>` element that specifies to what view you are "submitting" the data)?

Comment: I added template. And there are two `urls.py` - project root, app 'ex00'.

Comment: so exactly *what* has been printed in the console? Only the `POST CALLED`? Nothing else? Can you share the console output?

Comment: Yes, only `POST CALLED`. (except other print in `form_valid()`. I attached console output image.

Comment: the main problem is that I can not reproduce the fact that it does not print in case of `def is_valid()`. Do you have a (git) repository somewhere. Likely there is some small detail that we overlook.

Comment: I'll share my repository. Thank you for your kind answer, including the previous question.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer**: It calls it in the `post` method. The call to the `.clean()` method of the form, is part of the validation with `form.is_valid()`.

Indeed, if we take a look at the [source code `ProcessFormView` [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.2.x/django/views/generic/edit.py#L135-L144), the view that is inherited by a `CreateView`, `FormView` and `UpdateView`, we see:

> ```
> class ProcessFormView(View):
>
>     def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
>         form = self.get_form()
>         if form.is_valid():
>             return self.form_valid(form)
>         else:
>             return self.form_invalid(form)
> ```

The `post` method will thus first create a form, and then check if it is valid, and depending on that, it will call the `form_valid` method, or the `form_invalid` method.

The `clean()` method is *not* called by the view, but it is part of the `form.is_valid()` method to clean all individual fields, and then call `clean()` to validate items not related to a specific field.

Comment: Ok, now I understand that `form.is_valid()` is called by `post`. But why my overriden methods `is_valid()` and `clean()` were not called by `post`?

Comment: @mishy: I see that you have added a new constructor for your form. Did you update the `get_form_kwargs` to pass the `user`?

Comment: Not yet. But I thought that `'IS_VALID METHOD CALLED'` should have printed, regardless of `user`.  I could see that `form.cleaned_data` at overriden `form_valid()` was printed. As you explained, `form_valid` is called by `post`. If so, it means `if form.is_valid()` was excuted, right? Then I have no idea why I couldn't see `print` at overriden methods of `PublishForm`.

Comment: @mishy: are you sure you are triggering the right view, can you edit the question with your `urls.py`? It looks like it is accessing the wrong view, since a form that needs a `user` parameter, will error if you do not provide one.

Comment: I editted question. I tested my form with `fields = '__all__'`, selected user and posted. It worked and article was published. But I still cannot see those print.

Comment: @mishy: and you did not define the same view twice? Can you override the `post` method and print something to check that your `PublishView` "fires" and thus not some other view.